# SMS between two BlackBerry simulators

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

How do I write a program to send and receive SMS between two BlackBerry simulators using the BlackBerry JDE?

Answer (score 3):

You need to launch the simulators from the commmand line using these parameters:

```
/sms-source-port={uint}
/sms-destination-port={uint}
```

Launch two simulators instances and just switch source & destination ports on them!

Comment: I haven't tried this, but do you need to provide different PINs in the rimpublic.property file to send between the simulators?

Answer (score 1):

BB KB Article: [How To - Send SMS text messages between two BlackBerry Smartphone Simulators](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800792/801083/How_To_-_Send_SMS_text_messages_between_two_BlackBerry_Smartphone_Simulators.html?nodeid=1508042&vernum=0)