# send sms between two simulator in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

I want to send SMS to multiple contacts. I wrote the code and it works fine, but I want to test between two simulators.  I saw the solution in plenty of forums, [including StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403399/how-to-sent-and-recieve-sms-between-two-simulator-in-blackberry), but I am not able to make it work.

Comment: Hi I found solution myself.. i open simulator in different version and i test it                                             C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 4.5.0\simulator>fledge.exe /h
andheld=8300 /session=8300 /app-param=DisableRegistration /app-param=JvmAlxConfi
gFile:8300.xml /data-port=0x4d44 /data-port=0x4d4e /pin=0x2100000A /phone-number
=13659250971 /sms-source-port=5000 /sms-destination-port=5001 /app=jvm.dll

Comment: C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 5.0.0\simulator>fledge.exe /h
andheld=9700 /session=9700 /app-param=DisableResistration /app-param=JvmAlxConfi
gFile:9700.xml /data-port=0x4d4e /pin=0x2100000A /phone-number=13659250972 /app=
jvm.dll /sms-source-port=5001 /sms-destination-port=5000

Comment: you should post your solution as an answer and then accept it! :-)

Answer (score 3):

To expand on David's self-answer: To get this up and running, the phone number options are not strictly required (depending on what you want to do). If you set the sms ports correctly, you can use any phone number when sending the sms and it will go to the other emulator.

And to anyone blindly copying n pasting like I did, watch out for the extra spaces. So the 2 commands could be:

```
fledge.exe /handheld=8300 /session=8300 /app-param=DisableRegistration /app-param=JvmAlxConfigFile:8300.xml /data-port=0x4d44 /data-port=0x4d4e /pin=0x2100000A /sms-source-port=5000 /sms-destination-port=5001 /app=jvm.dll
fledge.exe /handheld=8800 /session=8800/app-param=DisableResistration /app-param=JvmAlxConfigFile:8800.xml /data-port=0x4d44 /data-port=0x4d4e /pin=0x2100000A /sms-source-port=5001 /sms-destination-port=5000 /app=jvm.dll
```

I have found the DisableRegistration parameter speeds up the start-up time, and makes the MDS functionality work properly (at least for 1 emulator running) - ymmv

Additionally, to do this while debugging in eclipse, I have found other problems. My setup was to run one simulator from command-line, and one from eclipse. Make sure your command-line simulator is using the same copy of "fledge.exe" and the same jvm as your eclipse copy. In my case I had 2 different installations of the BB plugin, and the simulators would not talk to each other. So use the above idea, but base the full command lines on the ones that are auto-generated by the eclipse debug config setup wizard.

Comment: Hello Richard, can you tell me how can I use the same fledge and JVM?

Comment: @Architact In the Eclipse debug config setup, you will find an auto-generated command line - this is the one to use to base your "command line" launch off. Do not just type in fledge.exe and hope for the best - use the generated command instead.